# How to compile c files more efficent with make

Tags: c++, c, makefile, compilation

I'm currently writing a toy OS. Since there are many c files where the gcc command does not change (except for the filename), is there a way to automatically select all .c files in a directory and compile and link them? Example: I create a new file, example.c
The i call

```
make
```

and the makefile does everything for me.

I do not want to use a script, only the makefile.

```
OBJECTS=kasm.o kc.o objects/kb.o objects/screen.o objects/string.o objects/system.o objects/util.o objects/idt.o objects/isr.o
ARGS=-ffreestanding
CC=gcc
TARGET=image/boot/kernel.bin

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

kasm.o: kernel.asm
    nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o kasm.o

kc.o: kernel.c
    gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kc.o $(ARGS)

objects/kb.o: include/kb.c include/kb.h
    gcc -m32 -c include/kb.c -o objects/kb.o $(ARGS)

objects/screen.o: include/screen.c include/screen.h
    gcc -m32 -c include/screen.c -o objects/screen.o $(ARGS)

objects/string.o: include/string.c include/string.h
    gcc -m32 -c include/string.c -o objects/string.o $(ARGS)

objects/system.o: include/system.c include/system.h
    gcc -m32 -c include/system.c -o objects/system.o $(ARGS)

objects/util.o: include/util.c include/util.h
    gcc -m32 -c include/util.c -o objects/util.o $(ARGS)

objects/idt.o: include/idt.c include/idt.h
    gcc -m32 -c include/idt.c -o objects/idt.o $(ARGS)

objects/isr.o: include/isr.c include/isr.h
    gcc -m32 -c include/isr.c -o objects/isr.o $(ARGS)
```

Edit: I was thinking at a way where this would be accomplished with wildcards

Comment: Please say how this one doesn't work so that we learn how to fix.

Comment: Oh.. I think the lower targets can be combined into one by using a makefile in the objects/ directory (yes, makefiles call each other recursively in some sense)

Comment: OT: Some years ago was doing my course project in university and had exactly the same problem while compiling same(!) files (as I was doing os kernel, too). Didn't find out the answer and didn't face this problem again as I use Windows

Comment: The best advice regarding `make` is to get a large OSS project (from Github, from example) and study its `Makefile`, with some documentation at hand, of course. You will learn many things this way. To answer your question: there is a way to tell `make` that the `.o` files depend on the files with the same name and `.c` termination but I just don't remember it.

Comment: If you are using `GNU` make then lookup `patsubst` and `wildcard`

Comment: It seems there isn't even needed to tell `make` that `.o` files depend on the `.c` files with the same name and how to build them. It is a built in rule. Read more here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/make-Deduces.html#make-Deduces

Comment: Have a look at the [musl makefile](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/Makefile) (musl has over 1000 .c files). It's the cleanest makefile for a non-toy project that I've ever seen.

Comment: It's worth starting a "proper" makefile (or your chosen tool) even for a "toy" (but not "throwaway" ...) project. Also getting it in version control - eg. git can let you do this locally without needing a server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual approach is to generate a list of `*.c` files from a particular path given using the [`$(wildcard ...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions) function.

To generate the corresponding list of `.o` dependencies you can use the [`$(patsubst ...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) function.

The rules to compile should be either the builtin rules for `%.o: %.c`, or you override these with your own.
You can also use [make templates](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) to provide modules for more complex stuff.

---

<sub>Related documentation:</sub>

- [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html#General-Search)
- [Writing Recipes with Directory Search](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipes_002fSearch.html#Recipes_002fSearch)